# jQuery Mobile click button but nothing happens

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery

I've poked around and found similar questions, but none of the solutions have worked.

I'm writing a simple (so far) app that will allow the user to select a number from 1-6 on a form, then display the that value (1-6) on another page. It works fine on my desktop, but when I try it from the iPhone emulator I click "Submit" and nothing happens at all... as if I didn't even click it.

I'm using jQuery 1.10.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1. I'll add that this is a PhoneGap app using Adobe's PhoneGap Build service.

Here's the code for my main page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Value Submit</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/themes/aw-theme2.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-mobile-min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).on('pageinit', function() {
      $(document).on('click', '#submitroll', function() {
            var dieRoll = $("#dieresult").val();

      $.mobile.changePage('valuedresult.html', { data: {arg1:dieRoll}});
      return false;
      });
    });

    $(document).on('pageinit', '#valued', function() {
       var dieRoll = $("#dieresult").val();
       $("#results span").html(dieRoll);
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="valued" data-theme='a'>
    <div data-role="header" data-header-theme='a'>
    <a data-icon="back" data-rel="back" back-btn="true">Back</a>
    <h1>Value</h1>
    <a data-icon="home" href="index.html" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme='a'>
    <form id="rollform">
    <select id="dieresult" name="dieresult">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="submitroll">Submit</a>
    </form> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the code for valuedresult.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Value Result</title>

<script>
$(document).on('pageshow', function(event) {
var url = $.url(document.location);
var arg1 = url.param("arg1");

$("#results span").html(arg1);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="valueresult" data-theme='a'>
   <div data-role="header" data-header-theme='a'>
       <a data-icon="back" data-rel="back" back-btn="true">Back</a>
       <h1>Value Result</h1>
       <a data-icon="home" href="index.html" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme='a'>
<div id="results">Result: <span></span>
    </div> <!-- results -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said, it works fine on a desktop browser, but nothing happens on the iPhone emulator when I click "Submit".

I've played around with this for quite a while, referring to other posts, documentation, etc... but I just can't seem to get it working. Hopefully I'm just missing something silly.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** I've noticed this piece of code `$.url`. This is not part of jQuery or jQuery Mobile. You're missing the Purl JavaScript URL parser plugin. You should add it in the first page's `head` tag.

Below you can find some fixes related to the code you've posted. I have removed the code which refers to the missing Purl JavaScript URL parser plugin as well.

In the first page, attaching the `click` event handler on the `document` element is enough. You don't need to include it inside a `pageinit` event handler. Moreover instead of using `return false;` it is better to use `event.preventDefault()` in order to prevent the default behavior of the event. I have removed some unnecessary code as well.

In the second page, I have modified your `script` and put it inside the jQM `page`. The reason is that when a jQM page is loaded through Ajax, the `script` inside the `head` tag are not loaded. An alternative solution would be to load this `script` on the first page's load.

I have modified your example as following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Value Submit</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document)
            .on('click', '#submitroll', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var dieRoll = $("#dieresult")
                    .val();

                $.mobile.changePage('valuedresult.html', {
                    data: {
                        arg1: dieRoll
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="valued" data-theme='a'>
        <div data-role="header" data-header-theme='a'>
            <a data-icon="back" data-rel="back" back-btn="true">Back</a>
            <h1>Value</h1>
            <a data-icon="home" href="index.html" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme='a'>
            <form id="rollform">
                <select id="dieresult" name="dieresult">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="submitroll">Submit</a>
            </form>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

valuedresult.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Value Result</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="valueresult" data-theme='a'>
        <div data-role="header" data-header-theme='a'>
            <a data-icon="back" data-rel="back" back-btn="true">Back</a>
            <h1>Value Result</h1>
            <a data-icon="home" href="index.html" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme='a'>
            <div id="results">Result: <span></span>
            </div>
            <!-- results -->
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document)
                .one('pageshow', '#valueresult', function (event) {
                    var parameters = $(this)
                        .data("url")
                        .split("?")[1];
                    parameter = parameters.replace("arg1=", "");
                    $("#results span")
                        .html(parameter);
                });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to review my code. I'll try out your changes and post my results! Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, I gave it a try... there's no change in the mobile browser - clicking the submit button does nothing; it's as if I'm clicking on the background or something. And now when I use the desktop browser, it isn't passing/capturing the value of arg1. 

Based on your edits, I can probably tweak the code with the URL parameters to get it to work. But I'm still at a loss as to why clicking the Submit button does absolutely nothing.

Thank you again for those edits. I'll play with them some more and see if I can get it to work. Further suggestions welcomed as well. :-)

Comment: Hmm, I've tested the code I posted both in desktop and PhoneGap app. Make sure that both HTML files are under the same folder when building the PhoneGap app (since changePage('valuedresult.html' tries to find the valuedresult.html at the existing path). I've also posted some images which depict the corresponding PhoneGap app running on an Android emulator.

Comment: Also note that in your first page you're using `$(document).on('pageinit', '#valued'` but the page id is `valueresult`.

Comment: Again, I really appreciate your help. I think I must be missing something very subtle because I just can't get this to work, even if I copy/paste your code above. It still doesn't even work on my desktop browser. 
I did verify that all of my HTML files are in the same directory.
So strange that it clearly works for you but not for me. Obviously the problem is on my end; I'm taking another look. 
Thanks again. :)

Comment: Now this is interesting... I managed to get it working on the desktop browser again by using your alternative solution (putting the second page's script in the first page's load). No change on the mobile browsers though. But progress is progress. :)

Comment: And another thing I just observed: if I change the Submit link from
 <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="submitroll">Submit</a> 
to 
<button id="submitroll" type="submit" data-theme="a" name="submitroll">Submit</button> 
it will now respond to a click. It doesn't take me to the result page, but it at least "clicks", which is an improvement (I think). Or at least a psychological improvement. :)

Comment: GOT IT! Almost...  
Normally, to test, I load the emulator then click on the link on the index.html page to get to this troublesome valued.html page. Well, for kicks, I renamed the troublesome "valued.html" to "index.html", replacing the previous index.html. I re-built and launched simulator... and it works! 
So the issue has something to do with how I'm getting to valued.html. Based on what I've learned the past couple days, I think I should be able to figure this out. If not, I'll create a separate post. Thanks again!!!